# gmock: check only one element of vector

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

As per the cheat sheet https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/v1_7/CheatSheet.md

one can use `ElementsAre(_,_,..)` to compare elements of a vector.

If we wish to pick only a particular element of the vector and put a comparator to the object at the (n+1)th entry, how would you pick up a single element?

Sample

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyPrimitiveClass1 class1_obj;
    MyPrimitiveClass2 class2_obj;
};
std::vector< MyStruct > myvec;
```

I need to check that `myvec` that is passed in a function is such that

```
myvec[n] == test_my_struct_obj
```

EDIT: 
Now, to complicate the problem, `myvec` itself is a field of a class, say `MySuperClass`, and what's being passed around is a `MySuperClass my_superclass_obj;`.

I need to check if

```
my_sperclass_obj.myvec[n] == test_my_struct_obj
```

For now I have this structure

```
EXPECT_CALL(mocked_obj, foo( 
                            Field(&MySuperClass::myvec,
                                  ElementsAre(_, _ .. n-1 times, 
                                              MyStructMatcher(), _)
                                  )    
                           )
            );
```

My idea is to escape the `ElementsAre` and do something cleaner. Does anyone have hints? (n00b here)

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate your problem with function, like:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<testing::Matcher<T>> matchNthElement(int index, int size, testing::Matcher<T> matcherForNthElement)
{
    std::vector<testing::Matcher<T>> result{N, testing::_};
    result[N] =  matcherForNthElement;
    return result;
}
```

And use with `ElementsAreArray` instead of `ElementsAre`:

```
auto matchContainerWithNthElement = matchNthElement(n, size, MyStructMatcher());
EXPECT_CALL(mocked_obj, foo( 
                            Field(&MySuperClass::myvec,


    ElementsAreArray(matchContainerWithNthElement.data(), 
                     matchContainerWithNthElement.size())

                                  )    
                           )
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `EXPECT_EQ` here:

```
EXPECT_EQ(test_my_struct_obj, myvec[n]);
```

Or:

```
EXPECT_THAT(myvec[n], Eq(test_my_struct_obj));
```

Comment: Umm, the problem is that myvec is itself a field of an object. So it's like
my_superclass_object.myvec[n] needs to be tested while my_superclass_object is being passed around.

So when I do EXPECT_CALL( mocked_obj, foo( Field(&my_sperclass_obj::myvec[n], MyStructMatcher( )  )  )  );

 It gives an error of using "invalid use of non-static data member". 
Is there more cleaner way to do this kind of a thing? (n00b here)

And I can't seem to nest EXPECT_THAT( ) in that EXPECT_CALL( )